# Ordering data from a table with the help of other table by using relationships with laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have the controller with the query:

```
$Comments = Comment::orderBy('id_parent', 'asc')->get();
```

And I have the Comment model:

```
class comment extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vote', 'comment_id', 'id_comment');
    }
}
```

I want to retrieve the comments data sorted in a specific way, every comment has multiply votes voted by different users, so the count('vote') is the number of votes for each comment. The problem is that I am stuck with how to call the specific votes function in the model so that it can count the column vote and order it either asc or desc.

That in the end I can have the $Comments sorted also by the total number of votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try as:

```
$Comments = Comment::withCount('votes')->orderBy('votes_count', 'asc')->get();
```

`withCount()` method is used when you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them, which will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

Comment: Am i doing wrong,      $Comments = Comment::where('vote_rd', $Politician)->orderBy('id_parent', 'asc')->withCount(['vote', 'votes' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('comment_id', 'like', 'id_comment');
}])->get();

Comment: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2440:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::vote()

Comment: You are using `vote` in your `withCount()` function wheras your relation is `votes`.

Comment: it works fine, right now, but is there a function that can sum the vote column(which is either +1 or -1) also and order it also by the sum of vote for each comment, using relationships?

Comment: No, you have to use join for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using sortBy:

```
$comments=Comment::with('votes')->get()->sortBydesc('votes');
foreach($comments as $comment)
{
   echo $comment->votes->count('vote');
}
```